# Submitting form data of a file from javascript to a contoller's function in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-7

I have the defined HTML of my form in create.blade.php and its js in form.js. I want to send the form data from the java-script to a laravel controller EventsContoller's function store. Whenever I press the submit button, the same url loads with a '?' at the end. Can anyone please solve my query?
Here is the code:

```
       **EventsController.php**:
    
     public function store(Request $request)
        {   
        //The controller function code
    
       }
    
        **create.blade.php**:
    
    The code for the form opening and closing and the submit button.
    @extends('inc.navbar')
    @include('inc.messages')
    
    @section('content')
    <body>
        <!--   BEGIN:CREATE FORM-->
        <div class="row">
            <div id="my_container">
                {!! Form::open(['class'=>'event-details col s12 m12 l12 p-0', 'id'=>'form'])!!}
                   //The form code
      {!!Form::close()!!}
                    <form class="buttons">
                        <div class="row center-align m-0">
                            <div class="submit_form">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">BACK</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        **form.js**:
    
    The function for submitting the form data sending data to the controller's store function.
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
     
    var start_dates = [];
    var end_dates = [];
    var start_times = [];
    var end_times = [];
 
    var no_of_days = $("#no_of_days").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < total_rows_of_dates; i++) {
        var start_date = $('#start_date' + i).val();
        start_dates[i] = start_date;
        var end_date = $("#end_date" + i).val();
        end_dates[i] = end_date;
        var start_time = $("#start_time" + i).val();
        start_times[i] = start_time;
        var end_time = $("#end_time" + i).val();
        end_times[i] = end_time;

        let current_date = new Date();

        if (end_date < start_date || new Date(start_date) < current_date || new Date(end_date) < current_date) {
            console.log('Please put different date');

        }
        if (start_time >= end_time) {
            console.log('Please put different time');
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (department.val() == "" || title.val() == "" || description.val() == "" || fees.val() == "" || speaker.val() == "") {
            console.log("Please enter all details");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
        console.log(start_dates);
        console.log(end_dates);
        console.log(start_times);
        console.log(end_times);  
    // var params  = "name="+name;"&department="+department;"&description="+description;"&fees="+fees;"&speaker="+speaker;"&no_of_days="+no_of_days;"&total_rows_of_dates="+total_rows_of_dates;"&start_dates="+start_dates;"&end_dates="+end_dates;"&start_times="+start_times;"&end_times="+end_times;
    // event.preventDefault();
    xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','http://localhost/sample_web/public/events',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onload=function(){
        console.log(start_dates);
        console.log(end_dates);
        console.log(start_times);
        console.log(end_times);    } 
        // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var params  = {name:name, department: department, description: description, fees:fees, speaker:speaker, no_of_days:no_of_days, total_rows_of_dates:total_rows_of_dates, start_dates:start_dates, end_dates:end_dates, start_times:start_times, end_times:end_times};
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
});
```

Comment: It sounds like when you are pushing the submit button, your form is submitting. Try putting ```e.preventDefault();``` before you declare var start_dates = []; so that it executes that first.

Comment: First of all thank you for responding to my question. Well I tried your solution and when I pressed the submit button, there was no change in the page and the console displayed the following errors: 1)Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/sample_web/public/events' from origin 'http://sample_web.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 2)Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Can you help me with this?

Comment: CORS is a popular error when developing application locally. Basically, you should only request `localhost` from `localhost`, and `sample_web.io` from `sample_web.io` - same domain. If you'd like to ignore cors, for the purpose of development, I suggest google "chrome run without cors".

Comment: @shithilshetty, I noticed your POST request is not passing a CSRF token. It could be contributing to this error too - check the docs at: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Now I am getting an error like create:621 POST http://localhost/sample_web/public/events 419 (unknown status), any idea on how can I resolve this?